# Context menu in WinRT Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, contextmenu, winrt-xaml

Is there any default way to have context menu in WinRT.

am migrating my WPF application to WinRT Xaml, and am in search of Context menu support in WinRT.

How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the AppBar is the best replacement for a ContextMenu. If you really need a hidden touch&hold sort of a context menu you could try the context [Menu control](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/tree/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Menu) from Callisto. Windows 8.1 adds a [MenuFlyout control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/27/new-controls-in-windows-8-1.aspx) which I think is similar to the one in Callisto.

Answer (score 0):

Why not opt for FlyOut Control?! IMHO it should support for any framework.

Answer (score 0):

[PopupMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208693) is the built-in class for context menu functionality. It has a limitation of 6 commands and provides a separator support. It is not a control, so it has no UI customization or design time support. You can look at this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Context-menu-sample-40840351) for how it is used.